# Is a disk/ata timeout exception dangerous?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have a few hard drives in mdadm RAID 5 configured to go to standby after a few minutes of inactivity. (Using hdparm.conf `spindown_time`.)

At irregular intervals I get messages like these in `dmesg`:

```
[ 1840.251661] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[ 1840.251722] ata4.00: failed command: SMART
[ 1840.251758] ata4.00: cmd b0/d5:01:06:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[ 1840.251759]          res 40/00:14:50:2e:04/00:00:02:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[ 1840.251858] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[ 1840.251888] ata4: hard resetting link
[ 1840.600742] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[ 1840.601521] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[ 1840.601547] ata4: EH complete
[337877.713988] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[337877.714019] ata4.00: failed command: SMART
[337877.714038] ata4.00: cmd b0/d5:01:06:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
[337877.714039]          res 40/00:04:90:10:81/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[337877.714089] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
[337877.714107] ata4: hard resetting link
[337878.063085] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[337878.063743] ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
[337878.063764] ata4: EH complete
```

I think the exception is caused by `smartd` when a drive does not wake up quickly enough.

There are no issues (that I can tell) in accessing the drives normally through the file system - it takes a few seconds longer than normal when they are asleep, but there are no exceptions.

Is this something I should worry about, as a potential symptom on something that could corrupt a drive over time?

Or can I safely ignore it as part of normal operation?

*Edit:*

By request: [`smartctl -a`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/561078/) for `sda`and `sde`, both disks are members of the array.

If `ata4`is the same as `scsi-4` then `sde` is the one that gave the error above, according to `/dev/disk/by-path`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide the output of the command `smartctl -a /dev/sda` (replace `sda` with all disks) and post on http://paste.ubuntu.com/). This will show whether your disks are trying too often to spin down in order to save energy (which may damage them). In addition, it will show other information such as temperature, and bad sectors.

Comment: Also do this while they are spun down and see if you get the same error.  You also might want to configure smartd to not poll the smart data while the disk is in standby to avoid waking it up unnecessarily.

Comment: @user4124 Added for two of the disks, the rest are similar - same model, same age, similar SMART values.

Comment: @psusi No errors from a couple of smartctl runs from the command line. But in this log there are almost four days between the two errors - five disks, smartd runs once a day and four days between errors should indicate it happens ~1 in 20 wakeups. But yeah, I can try to disable smartd polling on standby disks.

Comment: The http://paste.ubuntu.com/561078/ reports look fine to me. I would not worry for these disks. The error messages are for SMART accesses and as `psusi` says, get smartd not to poll the disks when in standby.

Comment: @user OK, will do. Thanks for the feedback to both of you.

Comment: The polling should not cause those errors, so I am a bit curious about why they are happening, but they won't cause any problem so you don't need to worry about it.  My guess is flaky disk firmware.

Comment: @psusi I would like to know why as well, but as long as they won't cause problems I'm happy to let it be. (I was entertaining the possibility that it was supposed to work that way.) I think I had the same (or similar) errors with another set of drives, WD Greens (while hese are Seagate Barracuda). I didn't pay much attention as the messages didn't look dangerous and made no difference in actual use, but when my previous RAID died after a year with a whole bunch of corrupt sectors on 3 out of 4 disks, I started to wonder...

Comment: For future readers with similar issues: This may or may not be related to the bug [SATA link power management causes disk errors](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/539467). The error details differ, but I did use SATA link power management.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message popping up in my Armbian running on Banana Pi. It turned out, I had a broken 5 volt pin in the molex cable powering the hard disk.

Oddly enough my 3.5 inch hardisk ran with just 12 volt supply working, but was constantly showing the same error as yours.

So if your Hard Disk passes the test, I recommend checking the power supply, try connecting the hard disk with a different sata power cable.

Hopes this saves some time , for anyone who faces such weird issues.